# Should a mutex be used in this context?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, mutex

Let's assume the following conditions. I have two threads that are both working on the same class. Both have access to the member variables of the class. However, none of the threads share reads/writes between the same member variables (one thread access set A of variables, and the other thread access set B of variables, with none of the variables in A being in B). Should I still use a mutex on both threads when accessing (either write/read) those variables for future proofing thread-safety?

Note: my understanding is that mutexes should only be used if the same variables have the possibility of being accessed by both threads. If they don't, I don't think mutexes should be used.

Comment: No need, writes/reads to different memory locations are thread-safe (although there could be false-sharing of cache lines leading to worse performance).

Comment: If one thread only accesses one half of the class and the other thread accesses the other half of the class then why is that just one class? Shouldn't you split it in two? You can then much easier ensure the two new classes don't share a cache line.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow That is a really good question/comment and it's probably very difficult to answer here in a complete fashion. The main idea is this is how the code is structured at this time and it isn't simple to change the structure easily. Even though what you are proposing seems like the right approach, it isn't feasible in this case. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Then you will have to pretend that there is such a split and just keep going. The split just makes it explicit and safer because you can't accidentally access the same member from both threads if they are split.